# Combinations with repetition problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A certain school of 10 children is visiting the local ice-cream factory to see how ice-cream is made. After the demonstration, the factory has 15 scoops of vanilla ice-cream and 2 scoops of chocolate ice-cream to distribute to the kids. How many ways can the ice-cream be distributed if each child must receive at least one scoop of ice-cream?

I've seen that the way to tackle this problem is to partition the ways into two cases: where the two scoops of chocolate ice-cream is given to two of any of the students and where two scoops of chocolate ice-cream is given to only one of the students. And in both, subtract the amount of ice cream given to satisfy the condition that all of them have at least one scoop of ice cream, and use combinations with repetition after that.

But what I cannot understand is why can't I just assume that the chocolate ice cream and vanilla ice cream as identical since what's being asked is how many ways to distribute the ice cream to the kids. By assuming they are identical, I can deduct 10 to the now 17 scoops of ice cream and use combinations with repetition with the remaining scoops.

Sorry for the long post, perhaps I'll reduce it later on.

Comment: "*What I cannot understand is why can't I just assume that the chocolate ice cream and vanilla ice cream as identical?*"  Suppose little Billy's favorite ice cream is chocolate and that he hates vanilla.  In the outcome where Billy gets two scoops, both of which chocolate, he's had the best day ever.  In the outcome where billy gets two scoops, both of which vanilla, he throws a tantrum and is upset.  Treating chocolate as different than vanilla, we can tell these two scenarios apart.  Treating them as the same, we can't.

Comment: Is anyone allowed to receive three or more scoops?

Comment: I assume that the scoops cannot be subdivided for some reason (otherwise the number of distributions would be infinite), but is it necessary that all 17 scoops be given to the children? Or can the teacher wisely leave 7 scoops behind to avoid all the whining?